# SQL conditional select and conditional where

Tags: sql, mysql, conditional-statements, case

I have a problem creating a view or a select statement. the problem could be due to poor design so any suggestions could help.

I will try to simplify the design as follows:

- A service table, service.id and service.name
- A product table, product.id and product.name
- A package table, package.id and package.name
- an Item table, item.id and service.id (can be null) and product.id (can be null) and package.id (can be null)

an item table could contain either a service.id or product.id or package.id

So my question is how can I create a view/select to show the item table selecting the item.id and if item.service_id is not null then get that and the service.name, otherwise if the item.product_id is not null then get that and the product.name or if the item.package_id is not null get that and the package.name?

I tried a mixture of using sql case statement but I couldn't get it to work! I keep getting the item table with redundant incorrect rows. I expected to get something like:

| Item ID | Service ID | Product ID | Package ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | NULL | NULL | Hair Cut |
| 2 | NULL | 30 | NULL | Shampoo |

Comment: There is definitely poor design here. You should use some kind of table inheritance or polymorphic association. Eg `Item (ItemId, Type CHECK (Type BETWEEN 1 AND 3))` and `ServiceItem (ItemId REFERENCES Item (ItemId), Type AS 1)` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query please:

```
CREATE VIEW ItemDetails AS
SELECT
    item.id AS ItemID,
    item.service_id AS ServiceID,
    item.product_id AS ProductID,
    item.package_id AS PackageID,
    CASE
        WHEN item.service_id IS NOT NULL THEN service.name
        WHEN item.product_id IS NOT NULL THEN product.name
        WHEN item.package_id IS NOT NULL THEN package.name
    END AS Name
FROM
    item
LEFT JOIN service ON item.service_id = service.id
LEFT JOIN product ON item.product_id = product.id
LEFT JOIN package ON item.package_id = package.id;
```

Comment: Thank you Yusof, this query did give me the results I wanted! From a design perspective. Do you think designing tables in such way is acceptable, or do you think they can be designed better.

Comment: You're welcome. The design you've proposed works but might lead to complex queries and scalability issues, and considering alternative designs like Class Table Inheritance or Polymorphic Association Tables could offer more flexibility and maintainability for evolving applications.

Comment: the CASE can just be `coalesce(service.name,product.name,package.name)`, if only one of the three ids is ever not null or if the service/product names cannot be null.